# Mesh color not rendering

Tags: libgdx

I am using some code like below to draw some arrows on with a SpriteBatch, and for some reason the shader is not using the color set with with the MeshBuilder API.  The vertex color attribute seems to be used correctly as well, but still no luck.  Any idea what am missing?  btw the custom arrow builder is to hardcode the stemdiameter and the coneheights so as to nnot derive it from the length and make the arrows different widths.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshPartBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.shapebuilders.BaseShapeBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.shapebuilders.ConeShapeBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.shapebuilders.CylinderShapeBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class InvasionPointerActor extends Actor {

    private final Mesh arrowMesh;

    public InvasionPointerActor(Vector3 start, Vector3 end) {

        MeshBuilder builder = new MeshBuilder();

        builder.setColor(Color.RED);

        builder.begin(Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.ColorUnpacked, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);

        CustomArrowShapeBuilder abuilder = new CustomArrowShapeBuilder();
        abuilder.build(builder, start.x, start.y, 0, end.x, end.y, 0, 0.05f, 0.5f, 10);

        arrowMesh = builder.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        arrowMesh.render(batch.getShader(), GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    }

    private class CustomArrowShapeBuilder extends BaseShapeBuilder {

        public void build(MeshPartBuilder builder, float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2,
                float capLength, float stemThickness, int divisions) {

            Vector3 begin = obtainV3().set(x1, y1, z1), end = obtainV3().set(x2, y2, z2);

            float length = begin.dst(end);
            float coneHeight = 300 * capLength;
            float coneDiameter = 2 * (float) (coneHeight * Math.sqrt(1f / 3));
            float stemLength = length - coneHeight;
            float stemDiameter = 7;

            Vector3 up = obtainV3().set(end).sub(begin).nor();
            Vector3 forward = obtainV3().set(up).crs(Vector3.Z);
            if (forward.isZero()) {
                forward.set(Vector3.X);
            }
            forward.crs(up).nor();
            Vector3 left = obtainV3().set(up).crs(forward).nor();
            Vector3 direction = obtainV3().set(end).sub(begin).nor();

            Matrix4 userTransform = builder.getVertexTransform(obtainM4());
            Matrix4 transform = obtainM4();
            float[] val = transform.val;
            val[Matrix4.M00] = left.x;
            val[Matrix4.M01] = up.x;
            val[Matrix4.M02] = forward.x;
            val[Matrix4.M10] = left.y;
            val[Matrix4.M11] = up.y;
            val[Matrix4.M12] = forward.y;
            val[Matrix4.M20] = left.z;
            val[Matrix4.M21] = up.z;
            val[Matrix4.M22] = forward.z;
            Matrix4 temp = obtainM4();

            transform.setTranslation(obtainV3().set(direction).scl(stemLength / 2).add(x1, y1, z1));
            builder.setVertexTransform(temp.set(transform).mul(userTransform));
            CylinderShapeBuilder.build(builder, stemDiameter, stemLength, stemDiameter, divisions);

            transform.setTranslation(obtainV3().set(direction).scl(stemLength).add(x1, y1, z1));
            builder.setVertexTransform(temp.set(transform).mul(userTransform));
            ConeShapeBuilder.build(builder, coneDiameter, coneHeight, coneDiameter, divisions);

            builder.setVertexTransform(userTransform);
            freeAll();
        }

    }

}
```

Was expecting the color attribute in the mesh vertices to render from the default color on the mesh builder.  Instead this is rendering with BLACK color and not RED.  The main redering loop uses the stage to act and then draw these actors.

Comment: You're borrowing a shader from the Batch. Is it a shader that you have customized to support having Normals and no UVs or texture? The default shader for SpriteBatch has vertex attributes of Position, Color, and then UVs and is incompatible with the mesh you created, so it will have undefined results when you render it.

Comment: I tried a default shader as well, and it the same result.  The default shader has position and color, but not sure about the UVs.  I am only using color here, and not texture coorindates.  is UV required to the shader as well?  this is the default shader I tried with ShaderProgram:  https://gamefromscratch.com/libgdx-tutorial-part-12-using-glsl-shaders-and-creating-a-mesh/

Comment: I’m not sure if you understand me. The word default means “what you get if you don’t change anything”. If you don’t change the shader that comes with SpriteBatch to one that doesn’t try to base its color off a texture, it won’t appear as you expect. UVs are usually for looking up texture coordinates. But the important thing is what your fragment shader is doing and whether it got passed color information from the vertex shader, which should get it from the vertex data.

Comment: OK sorry was not clear about my comment about the "default" shader.  I mean to say I have tried with very basic shaders, that have a_position, a_color, and uv texturecoords.  I learned a little more about it, as well as the code above.  It seems the color is getting taken from the texture coords UV parts of the vertice parts.  I have added texture coords Usage attribute to thee above too.  That actually made some difference where can see some colors, but they are affected by that textiure UV and are not filled as may see when using the shader lines.

Comment: There is also some factoring into the issue with the mesh builder helpers of the arrow, cone, cylinder used on the arrow building.  I cant use it out of the box and will do some refactoring to customize that logic, as it may be more for 3D instead of 2D...  Appreciate your consdeiration and feedbacks.   I may try to use lines to do it, or else convert this mesh into a texture somehow.

Comment: Your mesh you built doesn't have texture coordinates and you're not drawing it with a texture, so your shader shouldn't have either. You should remove the `Usage.Normal` since that is useless if you are just drawing a solid color. Then try this: https://pastebin.com/L67eimuW Just a basic shader for drawing pure color with no texture or lighting.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After looking further into the VertexInfo usage in the gdx logic of these Arrow, Cone, Cylinder mesh builders, they are using the UV texture coords.  This is why had so much trouble using only position and color attributes.  When adding that attribute, it did show some color, but it was oddly shown per a 3D mesh vertices with manny divisions.  Not so great for 2D usage as am doing here.  After all, I bailed on using this mesh, and went with Shader 2D lines without an arrow cap on the end...